SPARQL comparison problem using IF and AVG
By using the following SPARQL query in Protégé, I can get the average of all differences.
SELECT (AVG(?difference) AS ?averageDifference)
WHERE {
    ?originalData a validation:OriginalData .
    ?originalData validation:hasCollection ?originalCollection .
    ?originalCollection a validation:TimeSeriesCollection ;
                        validation:hasTemperature ?originalTemperature ;
                        validation:hasTimeStamp ?originalTime .

    ?counterfactualData a validation:CounterfactualData .
    ?counterfactualData validation:hasMaximumTemperatureChange ?maximumTemperatureChange .
    ?counterfactualData validation:hasCollection ?counterfactualCollection .
    ?counterfactualCollection a validation:TimeSeriesCollection ;
                               validation:hasTemperature ?counterfactualTemperature ;
                               validation:hasTimeStamp ?originalTime .

    BIND(ABS(?counterfactualTemperature - ?originalTemperature) AS ?difference)
}

But the problem is I want to see the result like true or false for the answer of if maximumTemperatureChange is greater than averageDifference. However, as I know it is the only way (Using SELECT (AVG(?difference) AS ?averageDifference)) to see the average of differences.
I tried different ways:

BIND(IF(?maximumTemperatureChange > (AVG(?difference)), true, false) AS ?result)
BIND(IF(?maximumTemperatureChange > ?totalDifference), true, false) AS ?result)
BIND(AVG(?difference) AS ?averageDifference) (prints wrong)
SELECT (IF(?maximumTemperatureChange > (AVG(?difference)), true, false) AS ?result)

And none of them gave the desired result. So, what else way I can use to achieve what I want?
I expect to see the result of checking if maximumTemperatureChange is greater than averageDifference using SPARQL.

Use (x > y as ?xBiggerThanY) in the query projection.  Since x > y is already a boolean value, you don't need to bind with if.  E.g.,
select
  (avg(?diff) as ?avgDiff) # or use `avg(?diff)` below as well
  (?avgDiff > 3 as ?biggerThanThree)
  (?avgDiff > 4 as ?biggerThanFour)
  (?avgDiff > min(?diff) as ?avgBiggerThanMin)
  (?avgDiff > max(?diff) as ?avgBiggerThanMax)
where {
  values ?diff { 3 3 4 5 }
}

produces:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| avgDiff | biggerThanThree | biggerThanFour | avgBiggerThanMin | avgBiggerThanMax |
====================================================================================
| 3.75    | true            | false          | true             | false            |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


I am using SNAP SPARQL from Protege. I suppose it does not support it, because when trying to select (avg(?diff) as ?avgDiff) and (?avgDiff > 3 as ?biggerThanThree) it shows problem even before executing. Also it does not support subqueries. Sparql Query tab does not work either (could not find exact solution).
